# Does missing logout event in SQL Server trace mean connection leak?

Tags: sql-server, database-connection

I am investigating possibility of unreleased SQL Server database connections. I ran SQL Server Profiler and collected event traces. Typically after an executed SQL command, I see "Audit Logout" event and often `exec sp_reset_connection` that indicates that connection is reused for a new command.

However, I track some SPIDs and see that after some SQL command (e.g. `INSERT`), there are no more events for the given SPID. Does this mean that connection is not released, stays open and can not be reused?

Comment: You should try: https://dba.stackexchange.com/